# Поменять местами min/max в списке

Tags: python, список

Всем привет, пытаюсь поменять мин и макс местами в списке.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему первый вариант работает, а второй нет? В чём тут подводный камень?

```
b = [5,4,3,2,1,10,12]
i, j = b.index(min(b)), b.index(max(b))
b[i], b[j] = b[j], b[i]
```

```
b = [5,4,3,2,1,10,12]
b[b.index(min(b))], b[b.index(max(b))] = b[b.index(max(b))], b[b.index(min(b))]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все дело в `max` и `min`:

```
b[b.index(min(b))], b[b.index(max(b))] = b[b.index(max(b))], b[b.index(min(b))]
```

1. Когда вы присваиваете к `b[b.index(min(b))]` значение `b[b.index(max(b))]`, вы записываете максимальное значение вместо минимального.
2. Далее в `b[b.index(max(b))]` вы ищете индекс максимального значения в списке, который вы присвоили в пункте 1, следовательно далее вы обратно присваиваете к максимальному значению минимальное из списка.

Здесь `i, j = b.index(min(b)), b.index(max(b))` вы заранее записали индексы минимального и максимального значения, поэтому в `b[i], b[j] = b[j], b[i]` вы перезаписываете два значения списка по индексам между собой.

Answer (score 2):

Пока писал код `Tehnorobot` всё объяснил, но вот если что проверка, что всё происходит именно так - сначала выполняется и присваивается то, что до запятой, в потом то, что после запятой. Для этого я написал вспомогательную функцию, которая печатает и возвращает значение, чтобы можно было отследить, что происходит:

```
def valprint(value):
    print(value)
    return value

b = [5,4,3,2,1,10,12]
b[b.index(min(valprint(b)))], b[b.index(max(valprint(b)))] = b[b.index(max(b))], b[b.index(min(b))]
```

Вывод:

```
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 10, 12]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 12, 10, 12]
```

Как можно видеть, когда функция вызывается второй раз, то максимальное значение 12 уже стоит на том месте, где был до того минимум. Поэтому именно на это место и попадает обратно минимальное значение из списка - именно этот элемент находит `b.index(max(b))`.